# How to wire TIA 568-c cable into cat5e connector?

Tags: networking, internet, home-networking

I am new to networking so I apologize if this is a bad question. I am going through my house and putting connectors in all my rooms that were wired for cat5e and I noticed that some rooms have cat5e cable with TIA 568-c written on it. The color diagrams on the connectors I purchased only list A and B connections. Am I able to put these connectors on TIA 568-c cat5e cable, and if so do I wire according to A or B? Or do they require a different kind of connector? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the markings simply mean that your cable *itself* was made to conform to various other parts of that standard.

[ANSI/TIA-568-C.0](http://innovave.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/TIA-568-C.0.pdf) does not define any new pin assignment. It says:

> **5.3.3.2 Eight-position modular jack pin-pair assignments**
>
> Pin/pair assignments shall be as shown in figure 4 *[T568A]* or, optionally, per figure 5 *[T568B]* if necessary to
>   accommodate certain 8-pin cabling systems. The colors shown are associated with 4-pair cable.
>
> NOTE - The choice of pin/pair assignment designation can be customer specific. For
>   example, see US Federal Government publication NCS, FTR 1090-1997 for US
>   Federal Government installations.

So you're still supposed to use the same T586A/B wiring. Technically the choice of colors is all up to you, the signal does not care (although paired pins must forever remain paired, otherwise Ethernet wouldn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Using `TIA 568-B`'s wiring and color code for `TIA 568-C` works fine for me for ethernet without any issues.